# Setting href property dynamically based on partial page

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog, materialize

I have an index.html page that has a link on it that displays modal dialog when clicked.

```
<div id="modal1" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <h4>Modal Header</h4>
        <p>Modal sample text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <a href="#" class="modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">Close</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also index page displays partial pages inside a `ui-view`:

```
<div class="" ui-view>

</div>
```

The link that opens the modal is on the index page in the , so it is visible on any page. The problem I am having is when `Close` button is clicked, the modal dialog closes but then the user is taken to the login page. 
This is happening because `href="#"`. In order for it to be taken the a page should be something like `#/page1`. So it has to be set dynamically as the user navigates through the site. I can't seem to figure out a way to do that. Can anyone help?

The page url is something like this:

> http://localhost:77777/index.html#/page1

So I'd need to capture the page it is on and assign it to `href` property dynamically. How could I do that?

Comment: Sorry, just trying to understand the problem. You already noticed it. Couldn't you just make this anchor tag a button and not use the hash? Also, you could pass window.location.path in your click event handler and set the location from it to where you want the user to go..

Comment: Is there a way to set the `href` to  window.location in angular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use a button and ng-click?

something like:

```
<div id="modal1" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <h4>Modal Header</h4>
        <p>Modal sample text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button ng-click="closeModal()" class="modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">Close</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

And on the controller:

```
$scope.closeModal = function(){
    //your code to close the modal window
}
```

Hope it helps